# Change Font Size for only one multibind binding on DataGridTextColumn WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 properties that I multibind to a DataGridTextColumn. I want to make the first property display in a smaller font than the second property. How can I do that?

Here is the DataGridTextColumn
i.e)

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding
            StringFormat="{}{0}&#x0a;{1}" >
            <Binding
                Path="FirstName"/>
            <Binding
                Path="LastName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

FirstName and LastName are the two String properties I'm displaying with a new line separating the two. I would like FirstName to be smaller than LastName by just changing the xaml code. I do not want to do it through a viewmodel. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and use individual `TextBlock` or `Run` elements to style the different parts of the text:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="8" /><Run Text="&#x0a;" /><Run Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for